# If $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, then $\left|\varphi\right|\le\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|\varphi'(x)\right|$

Tags: calculus, analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $K:=\operatorname{supp}\varphi$. By the mean value theorem, $$\forall-\infty<a<b<\infty:\exists c\in(a,b):\varphi'(c)=\frac{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)}{b-a}\tag1$$ and hence $$\left|\varphi(a)-\varphi(b)\right|\le\sup_{c\in\mathbb R}\left|\varphi'(c)\right|\left|a-b\right|\;\;\;\text{for all }a,b\in\mathbb R\tag2.$$ So, $$\left|\varphi(a)\right|\le\left|\varphi(0)\right|+\sup_{c\in\mathbb R}\left|\varphi'(c)\right|\sup_{x\in K}\left|x\right|\;\;\;\text{for all }a\in\mathbb R\tag3.$$

> However, I've read that $\left|\varphi\right|$ is actually bounded by $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|\varphi'(x)\right|$. How can we show that?

Comment: Where did you read this? I think the statement is false.

Comment: It is slightly sad that you come here to make us check an obviously wrong statement, but choose to vanish into thin air when asked about the source of said statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you need to factor in the size of the support somehow.

Else, given some function $\phi$, you can consider $\phi_r:x \longmapsto \phi(rx)$ where $r>0$ is very small. Every $\phi_r$ is smooth compactly supported and has max-norm the max-norm of $\phi$; the max-norm of $\phi_r’$ is $r$ times the max-norm of $\phi’$ so can be arbitrarily small.

Now, if $\phi$ has support in $[-1,1]$, and if $|a| \leq 1$, there exists $r$ such that $|a-r| \leq 1$ and $\phi(r)=0$. So we know that $\phi(a)-\phi(r)$ can be written as $(a-r)\phi’(c)$ for some $c$, so that $|\phi(a)| \leq 1*|\phi’(c)| \leq \|\phi’\|_{\infty}$.